# 'List does not exist' when editing a publishing page?

Tags: error, publishing-page

I get an error message...

"List does not exist"

when I attempt to edit a new page within a publishing site.

The log file doesn't provide me with any additional details...

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

I'm using a custom master page.

Just wondering what could be causing this error...?

Comment: Is this localized or happening in all sub-sites of a particular site collection? If it's a wide-spread issue, you might have the the collection in read only mode. This can happen when doing stsadm backups that fail before returning the collection to read-write.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I ultimately changed the default page layout that was being used for new pages.  I had been using a custom one by default.  I never identified exactly what the issue was with the one I was using but once I switched it, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're deploying the master page through a feature?

In your master page module Elements.xml, remember to add List="116", like the following snippet shows:

```
<Module Name="MasterPages" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage"> 
  <File Path="MasterPages\custom_main.master" Url="custom_main.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" /> 
</Module>
```

In order for the changes to be correctly applied, delete the masterpage from the master page gallery, and deploy the solution again.